# How to show 4000 characters in RDLC report

Tags: rdlc

I have bind my dataset to RDLC report, in one of my dataset column I have 4000 characters when I bind it, I can only see 365 characters at runtime.
How to show all 4000 characters in RDLC report ?

Thanks in advance for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A limit of 365 characters is very strange.

Check `Column.MaxLength` property in your `ReportDataSource` and verify that the `TextBox.CanGrow` property is set to `True`.